# Codeigniter: Storing variables globally in a controller - How do I do this on CI? And is it more efficient?

Tags: php, performance, codeigniter

I have this function in a CodeIgniter Controller that gets variable and sets confgurations for sending an email:

```
// Sends to email the results 
public function send_mail($id, $name, $msg, $send){

    if ($send) {

        $ci = get_instance();
        $config['protocol']  = "smtp";
        $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
        $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
        $config['smtp_user'] = "myname@potato.pro"; 
        $config['smtp_pass'] = "ilovepotatos";
        $config['charset']   = "utf-8";
        $config['mailtype']  = "html";
        $config['newline']   = "\r\n";
        $config['crlf']      = "\r\n";
        $config['validate']  = FALSE;

        $ci->load->library('email');
        $ci->email->initialize($config);

        $ci->email->from('myname@potato.pro', 'Keyword Alerting System (KAS)');
        $list = array('myname.fname@gmail.com', 'sagi@potato.pro');
        $ci->email->to($list);
        $this->email->reply_to('no-reply@potato.pro', "KAS Alert $kas_keyword");
        $ci->email->subject('KAS Alert!');
        $ci->email->message("text");
        $ci->email->send();

    } 

}
```

So whenever this function is called it sets these configs. 
I want to make it much more efficient.

Is there a more efficient way to store stuff like that for all the controller?

Can I just add this in the __construct function? will the $config variable be global for the Controller?

Can I include

```
    $ci->load->library('email');
    $ci->email->initialize($config);
```

too?

Will this be efficient? Or is it better to call them only when the function is called?

Bottom line:

Storing variables globally in a controller - How do I do this on CI? And is it more efficient? What are the cases that storing variables globally are more recommended.

Comment: make a send email function in your model call this function using model. Just add your function in model and call and pass args from controller

Comment: Yes this is an option, the thing is that this function gets called several times, and sets the variables and loads them for each email. 
So is it more efficient maybe to call it from  the construct and make it somehow global for all functions (less processing work) ?

Comment: try http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/03/how-to-send-email-in-codeigniter-smtp.html. Then better to create a new config file

Comment: It sounds like you want to save these in a separate config file. You can do so by added these configurations to a file called email.php and saving it in the config folder. The you don't need to do the initialize part. I'm not sure if its quicker, maybe you can benchmark it and find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to make a parent controller.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

var $url;

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    // *********************** Load Library ****************************
    $this->load->library('session');
    //**************** set value to $url
    $this->url = "https://192.168.10.46/soap/soap.php?wsdl";
   }
}
```

so you will get the $url value from any controller which extended from MY_Controller, like this

```
$this->url;
```

Also look in here. http://blog.aztora.com/codeigniter-storing-variables-globally-in-a-controller-how-do-i-do-this-on-ci/